# Turning WiFi off, VS. disabling the driver

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter

Sometimes, when I am not able to connect to a WiFi network, I turn off WiFi by clicking on this button:

[image]

When that doesn't work, meaning, the WiFi network still has trouble connecting, I disable the network adapter, and then re-enable it. This little window pops up: [image]

What is happening under the hood *different* between these 2 scenarios. And why would disabling the WiFi adapter be any better?

Comment: "When that doesn't work" - what do you mean by this? Clicking the icon doesn't turn off the wifi?

Comment: I mean the wifi doesn't connect for some reason, and the wifi says 'cant connect to this network'. Edited post for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your problem might be solved by disabling power saving (Power management) for wifi adapter in Device manager. This is occurring in quite many devices and this should fix the problem. Note that after every big update it may be reverted.

Secondly, disabling wifi does not disable device. In that sense, depending on OS it kills the power delivered to the device or completely turns of drivers for device which results in software reset of device. Turning off wifi keeps drivers running on the system.